# Poisson process admits a continuous modification

Tags: probability-theory, fake-proofs, poisson-process

Let $X_t$  be a Poisson process.

Define $Y_t = X_t - t$.

Note that $\Bbb{E}[X_t^k] = \sum_i \left\{{k \atop i}\right\} t^i$, where 
$\left\{{k \atop i}\right\}$ denote [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Now compute 
$$\Bbb{E}[Y_t] = \Bbb{E}[X_t  - t] = 0 $$
 $$\Bbb{E}[Y_t^2] =\Bbb{E}[X_t^2  - 2 X_t t +t^2] =  \Bbb{E}[X_t^2]  - t^2 = t $$

If we compute a higher moment (please double check)
$$\Bbb{E}[Y_t^4] = \Bbb{E}[X_t^4] - 4t \Bbb{E}[X_t^3] + 6 t^2\Bbb{E}[X_t^2] - 4t^3\Bbb{E}[X_t] +t^4 = 3 t^2 +t $$

The last equality comes from the fact that

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[X_t^4]
&= t^4 + 6 t^3 + 7 t^2 + t\\
-4t\Bbb{E}[X_t^3] &= -4t( t^3 + 3 t^2 + t)\\
6t^2\Bbb{E}[X_t^2] &=  6t^2( t^2 + t)\\
-4t^3\Bbb{E}[X_t] &=  -4t^3( t)
\end{align*}

In light of this, for the compensated Poisson process,

$$\Bbb{E}[(Y_t-Y_s)^4] \leq K (t-s)^2$$

Can we apply [Kolmogorov's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) to conclude that  $Y_t$ admits a continuous modification?

There is probably an error in my computations, or I am missing something in the hypothesis of Kolmogorov's continuity theorem.

But I don't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You showed that $E(Y_t^4)=3t^2+t$ hence $E(Y_t^4)=\Theta(t)$ when $t\to0$ and $E((Y_t-Y_s)^2)=\Theta(|t-s|)$ is not $O((t-s)^{1+c})$ with $c>0$ when $t-s\to0$.

Comment: Notice that $Y_t - Y_s \stackrel{d}{=} Y_{t-s}$, from which we find that $$ \mathbb{E}[(Y_t - Y_s)^4] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{t-s}^4] = (t-s)(1+3(t-s)). $$ So we cannot apply the Kolmogorov-Centsov theorem. This is quite expected, since sample paths $t \mapsto Y_t$ have jump discontinuities $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Answer (score 0):

> Before you read this i suggest you to draw a monotonically non-decreasing, non constant, continous function, whose range is $\mathbb{N}_0$.

Note that if $X_t$ admits a version $Y_t$ that is continous (here you can even assume that all paths are continous), $X\overset{\text{fidi}}{=}Y$ i.e. there equal in their finite dimensional distributions. That means $Y_t$ is Poisson distributed for all $t>0$ and can therefore only reach values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. But by the distributional properties of $Y$, $Y$ has also a.s. monotonically non decreasing paths.
If $Y$ would be continous for all $\omega \in \Omega$ then
$0<\lambda t e^{-t \lambda}=\mathbb{P}(Y_t=1)\leq \mathbb{P}(\exists_{q\in \mathbb{Q}, q\leq t}Y_q \in (0.5,0.75))\leq \sum\limits_{q\in \mathbb{Q}, q\leq t} \mathbb{P}(Y_q \in (0.5,0.75))=0$
which makes no sense.

Here I assumed that $X$ is a homogenous Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$.

Answer (score 0):

See also my answer to the second question here - a Poisson process also can't admit a left continous modification:

[predictable $\Rightarrow$ left continous? progressive $\Rightarrow$ adapted and left continous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734221/predictable-rightarrow-left-continous-progressive-rightarrow-adapted-and/4734888#4734888)